# mysql_get_server_info() returns NULL but everything works OK

Tags: mysql, c

The title says it all. Calling `mysql_get_server_info` returns `(null)` but everything works fine.

`mysql_get_client_info()` returns the correct value: `6.1.6`

What can be the reason I don't receive the correct server information `5.7.17-log`?

Comment: From where are you running this code?  Is there a MySQL server running there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_get_server_info` assumes that there is an existing connection to a MySQL server created earlier in the running process. You'd need to call `mysql_connect` first, if you want it to return anything.

This is much easier to visualize (and more future proof) with `mysqli_get_server_info`, which takes an initialized `MySQLi` object as a parameter.

Comment: OMG, OMG, OMG! Shame on me. For debugging reasons I moved the output few lines higher [before it worked]. I did not realize I changed the order. Yes, as Sheldon Cooper said: **I should not work after 9pm**. Thx!

Comment: @AlBundy For the love of Pete! Change to `mysqli` before the boogey men get you!

Comment: Hm, I am using the MySQL C Connector. There is only the `mysql` version. Where should be the `mysqli` version?